# Error: Filter chain halted as :correct_user rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on review applications. In this app, users can post their own project and other users review to it. But I faced this error when other users try to edit their own reviews. To edit a project is only allowed to project owners. But to edit reviews should be allowed to users who wrote its review.

How can I divide this authentication?

`/controllers/projects_controller.rb`

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @project.attributes = create_params
    if @project.save
      redirect_to @project
    else
      render edit_project_path(id: @project.id)
    end
  end

  private

  def signed_in_user
    unless user_signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    unless current_user.projects.include?(@user)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

`/controllers/reviews_controller.rb`

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_projectct, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @review.attributes = create_params
    if @reviews.save
      redirect_to prokect_path(id: @review.project_id)
    else
      redirect_to project_path(id: @review.project_id)
    end
  end

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find_by_id(params[:project_id])
  end

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    unless current_user.review.include?(@review)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

`routes.rb`

```
resources :projects do
  resources :reviews
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to define a separate `correct_user` filter on the reviews controller?

Comment: Ah, I will try thanks.

Comment: I have defined `correct_user` on the reviews controller. I could not do that.

Comment: What do you mean you could not do that? Can you edit your question to show your attempt?

Comment: Sorry I added @maxpleaner

Comment: Why are you using the `include` method there? Why not just compare with `==`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify that the user has written the review, why not compare like this:

```
@review.user == current_user
```

By the way, this is an authorization verification, so if the user does not have the right to edit the review, you should return a 403 (Forbidden) instead of a redirect.

Gems like pundit or cancancan may help you doing that properly

Comment: Thanks I'll do that :)